# dotnet core rc4 - nuget config on linux not quite working

Tags: .net, nuget

I would like to use an alternative nuget repository and it requires an apikey.

Using the installed `nuget` command I can add a Source and Apikey

```
nuget sources Add -Name Artifactory -Source https://myserver/nuget/nuget
nuget setapikey <my encrypted key> -Source Artifactory
```

My first conundrum is that I can't find where this config is saved. Certainly not in ~/.nuget/NuGet/NuGet.Config

The real issue is that it doesn't work anyway.

If I manually modify the config file, I can start using `dotnet nuget [command]`. This almost works, but no matter what I do, the apikey is not honored.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<config>
    <add key="DefaultPushSource" value="https://myserver/api/nuget/nuget" />
</config>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="Artifactory" value="https://myserver/api/nuget/nuget" />
  </packageSources>
  <apikeys>
      <!-- tried alternating between these to no avail -->
      <!--<add key="Artifactory" value="encryptedsecret" />-->
      <add key="https://myserver/api/nuget/nuget" value="encryptedsecret" />
  </apikeys>
</configuration>
```

this *almost works*

```
dotnet nuget push mypkg.nupkg
>error: Encryption is not supported on non-Windows platforms.
```

however, if I supply the apikey on the command line it works!

```
dotnet nuget push mypkg.nupkg -k encryptedsecret
>your package was pushed
```

How can I configure nuget to not require the encrypted secret on the command line?

Where does the config go when I use `nuget setapikey...`?